# C# Creating callable like PHP

Tags: c#, methods, callable

I have done a lot of PHP in the past and there you where able to pass trough code as a parameter, if Im right it was called a *callable*.

This is how it looked like:

```
METHOD('Parameter', function() { 
echo "Hey!";
});
```

is This possible in C#? Cause I would love to do that. to execute that function as a paramenter in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My awnser that I found quickly after posting this question:

**Usage:**

```
TestMethod ("Lambda", () => {
  Console.WriteLine("Expression");
});
```

**Method:**

```
public void TestMethod (string name, Action action) {
 if(name == "Lambda") {
   action.Invoke ();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass in a callable function to another method? The easiest way to do that would be to use a [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter:

```
void MyMethod(Action<string> passedInFunc)
{
    passedInFunc("Hey");
}
```

And then call it:

```
MyMethod(s => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
});
```

An Action represents a function that do not return any value, while a Func is a function that does return a value.

If you do not want to pass in any arguments to your Action, there is a [non-generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) version you can use.

In the end, these are just [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx), so you could also define your own custom delegate and pass that one instead.

Comment: Thanks, after I posted it LambaExpression game into me and I figgured it out. But couldn't find this question back. Ill awnser it myself. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @joey FYI in the middle of the top bar, you can click on your avatar to access your profile. There you can find the questions you asked.